# What happened to Wakanda in Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield, black-panther-2018

Current season 5 of the tv show, the Earth is pretty apocalyptic (spoiler free).

It is set in the Marvel universe and has mentioned the events of previous Marvel movies before, so I don't believe the show is based in an alternate timeline where Wakanda doesn't exist.

What happened to the city, people and technology of Wakanda? Where did it all go?

Comment: Boom, maybe? I mean all their vibranium could've absorbed all that energy safely, on the other hand it could just have easily absorbed all that energy until eventually releasing it in a big explosion. probably on the order of a very large nuclear bomb

Comment: Just like the rest of the planet. Kaboom.

Comment: Hi and welcome. I've made a little edit for you with regards to our policies on [tag hierarchies](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4861/68872) take a quick read at that to learn a thing or two about our policies :)

Comment: Why would you expect it to somehow have a different fate than the rest of the planet?  It’s possible that the vibranium helped keep it as one of the larger chunks, but there is nothing we’ve seen to imply it would be spared or otherwise survive.

Comment: @phantom42, even if wakanda country and city was destroyed, there are the wardogs spread all over the world. One or two would surely have managed to survive and scavenge tech remnants. Also, there is the whole outreach and refugee program which would have made wakandan tech (and some wakandans) available in N.America where the lighthouse was built. Something would surely have made it onto the lifeboat?

Comment: @Edlothiad, thanks for the headsup. Will keep it in mind for future question.

Answer (score 7):

## Mostly, because spoilers

I think a lot of it boils down to, Season 5 started in December 2017 whereas Black Panther released two months later. If they started talking about Wakanda in the TV series months before the movie it would take away some of the shock and awe.

**Further explanation**

In previous episodes, when a movie was released, it usually did not effect what SHIELD was doing (Guardians, Deadpool, Dr Strange, Thor, etc). The exceptions being Captain America movies.

In those cases, they had a direct tie-in in the episode just following the movie release. For instance, in Captain America: Winter Solder, Nick Fury is shot (among other spoilers), and immediately following in SHIELD, Fury shows up injured.

This was not possible with Black Panther. The current season if SHIELD started in December; two months before. If they started talking about

> "mines of vibranium" and "Wakandan bird ships"

it would take some of the mystery out of the movie.

Now, it is entirely possible that later in the series, the tech could have been used during the escape, but to what end? Wakanda was hoarding their technology away from the rest of the world until the very end at the U.N. conference. But by then in the timeline, SHIELD was in the future so they wouldn't know about the reveal.

So how would the plot be furthered by finding a vibranium bracelet? They wouldn't know what to do with it anyways.

Comment: I don't know if the question has been edited out of sync with your answer, but they don't line up.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens, My original answer still stands, but I added more details.

Comment: Timely tie-ins are now a lot more difficult between the movies and tv shows as the movie timelines are now completely out of sync. BP takes place a week after Civil War, which is now years ago, while AoS still appears to take place present day (excluding time jumps, obviously).

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens, only edit to question was to add a 'marvel' tag.

Comment: What does "mostly, because spoilers" mean? Is that slang I'm not recognizing?

Comment: Means: "The majority of the reason is because of spoilers".

Comment: Or in other words, "they didn't mention Wakanda at all because they didn't want to ruin the mystique of Wakanda before the release of Black Panther".

Comment: There are WAY more tie-ins than just the "Captain America" movies. Almost all movies that are based on earth are connected with agents of SHIELD. The events in the Avengers movies such as the battle in New York are mentioned a lot of times.